# get stuck to create table for answers for forum?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, forum

I'm trying to create a `forum` using jsp and mySql database.

So, basically i'm getting stuck to create a design for table.

I've this table:

```
create table if not exists thread_question(
question_id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
person_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
question_title VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
question VARCHAR(100000) NOT NULL,
question_dateTime VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(question_id)
);

create table if not exists thread_answer(
answer_id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
person_name_answer VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
answer VARCHAR(100000) NOT NULL,
answer_dateTime VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(answer_id)
);
```

Here if i fetch all those answers, it shows the same answers according to all questions. Here i get stuck..

So, how to show an answer with separate question so that it would show with different question. Hope so you understand what i'm trying to say.

***Surely, Help would be appreciated!!***

Comment: How are these two tables linked? How would you know which answer belongs to which question? you might need to add a field which will be foreign key in thread_answer to thread_question's question_id field.

Comment: Okay.. finally i understood that i would need to insert `question's id` inside answer's table... But how would i insert question's id inside answer's table?? any idea..?

Comment: alter table statement..see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) if table is already created else add same field definition as mentioned in questions table add references question(question_id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect between your answers and your questions.

So you need to define the `thread_answer` table more like this:

```sql
create table if not exists thread_answer(
    answer_id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
    question_id INT NOT NULL references thread_question(question_id),
    person_name_answer VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    answer VARCHAR(100000) NOT NULL,
    answer_dateTime VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(answer_id)
);
```

When you store a record in this table, you have to include the `question_id` of the question that is being answered. When you prepare the answer form in you jsp, make sure you include the question_id number in it as a hidden field.

When you retrieve all the answers to a question, you can add `question_id = NNNN` to your `WHERE` part and then you'll get just the answers to that question.